# Fall Into, go into — interchangeable?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I have this question about the interchangeability of "*fall into*" and "*go into*":

> 1. The airplane ***fell/went*** *into* a tailspin.
> 2. The economy ***fell/went*** *into* a decline.
> 3. He ***fell/went*** *into* a depression.
> 4. He ***fell/went*** *into* some bad habits.

Is "*fall*" or "*go*" not appropriate in some of the sentences?

Comment: 4 would not use "went" it would probably use "fell" or "got". The rest are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentence 1:  Either way works. No difference in meaning. An airplane can literally "go" or "fall"_ downward_.

Sentence 2: Either way works. In this case, the economy  went or fell *downward* figuratively (to a worse condition).

Note that in both 1 and 2, the subjects (airplane or economy) are inanimate, so there is no question of *intent* or *volition*.

Sentence 3: Either works, but "fell" could be seen as attributing the depression to outside forces, whereas "went" would not, because it implies the person is assumed to have some *choice* in the matter (less or more, depending on whether the speaker sees depression as a *disease* or as a *failure to try* to keep a positive attitude.))

Sentence 4: "Fell", as in #3, implies that the habits *happened to him*, not by his desire, but perhaps because of inaction, or of being in a bad place (among friends who used drugs, for example). This minimizes his blame in the matter. It wasn't really his fault; he just "fell".  We might even say he **fell in**  with a *bad crowd*, and [consequently] **picked up** some bad habits (like falling on the ground, and "picking up" dirt on one's pants.) Thus he is *exonerated*, in the eyes of the speaker.  (If it's his mom speaking, that's what she'll claim at his trial.)

But if he "went into some bad habits", that would imply that he intentionally sought them out.  And we wouldn't say it that way!

We might say he *acquired* some bad habits, or he *got into* some bad habits. These are not *exculpatory*, as the above, but both are neutral—that is, *non-judgemental*.

But, If we wanted to put blame on him, we might say, for instance  "He has **taken up** smoking. (or, more antiquatedly, "He has **taken to** smoking") That is, the speaker thinks that he *could have refrained*, but that  he *chose* to "take" the habit.

So you see that "went" vs. "fell" doesn't matter with regard to **things**, but it can matter, in *subtle* ways,  in regard to people.

Answer (score 1):

Well "falling" is a type of "going". It implies motion; movement, change.

You could use other words as well.

> The European nations sleepwalked into war.
>
> The patient slipped into a coma.
>
> The drunk man slumped into a stupor.

So the defining aspect is **[verb] [preposition] [noun]**

"into" is typically the correct preposition, but occasionally, depending on context, other may work as well (or even better).

Finally, to really answer you question, "to fall" usually has negative connotations, while "to go" or "to become" are far more neutral. This is one of the reasons why you would be more likely to say "I fell into depression" than "I went into depression".

Comment: I would also add that "went" implies volition on the part of the one going, while "fell" implies accidental. So when you say someone "fell into some bad habits" you are subtly absolving them of guilt for their bad habits. "Got into some bad habits" (I wouldn't use "went" there) puts more blame on the subject.

Comment: So, "***go*** *into some habits*" is standard English?

Comment: @meatie you can say "he **got** into some bad habits" or "he is **getting** into some bad habits" equally "he *fell* into some bad habits" or "he is *falling* into some bad habits". However, things like "he *goes* into some habits", "he *went* into some habits", "he *is going* into some habits" are all incorrect.

Comment: So, in sentences 1, 2, and 3, the usages of "fall into" and "go into" are standard English?

Comment: All of your examples are about proceeding to a presumably WORSE situation. That is why "fell" is appropriate (actual downward motion, like the airplane, or a metaphorical fall, to a worse condition) It is rare to say someone or something "fell" into a BETTER situation.

Comment: @meatie:  your point about "volition" is good, but we need to add that airplanes and economies aren't assumed to _have any volition_, so usimg "went" with such inanimate objects doesn't connote volition.